# Is it a subset of $M_{22}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I recently have been studying linear algebra by myself with a book, Linear Algebra: Step by Step.

While studying, I had a curiosity that could be simple after looking at the following example.

---

## Problems

Let $M_{22}$ be the set of 2 by 2 matrices. From the last section we know that this set is a vector space. Let $S$ be a subset of $M_{22}$, containing matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$

Show that $S$ is not a subspace of $V$.

## Solutions

We need to show that one of closure conditions (a) or (b) of Proposition (3.5) fails.

Let $$u = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ be vectors in the subset $S$. Then

$$u + v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 + 1 & b + 0 \\ c + 0 & d + 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$$

Hence $u + v$ is not a member of the set $S$ because the elements in $S$ are of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ but $u + v = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$. The first entry in the matrix $u + v$ needs to be 1, not 2, to qualify as an element of the subset $S$. Therefore $S$ is not a subspace of the vector space $M_{22}$.

---

## Questions

Here, since the result matrices $u + v$ are a 2 x 2 matrices, is it correct to understand that it is a subset of the vector space $M_{22}$?

Comment: Yes it is a sub*set*, it just is not a sub*space* [as your argument shows].

Comment: $U$ is a subset of $V$ simply requires ( by definition )  $x\in V\text{ } \forall x\in U$, and has nothing to do with the binary operation defined on $V$. So the condition to be a subspace is much more complex than being a subset, since the former requires binary operation issues, and a subspace must be a subset by definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks to @coffeemath, this part is clearly understood.

Comment: Thanks to @Asigan, I was able to understand more closely. Thank you.

Comment: I'd give the book's author a grade of "F" for the wording of the question. It seems the author meant "consisting of those matrices of the form ..."" but that is NOT what was said. The question did NOT exclude the possibility that $S$ also contained other matrices, as well as all (or maybe just some-the wording is doubly ambiguous) matrices of the given form.

Comment: “Since the result matrices $u+v$ are a $2\times 2$ matrices”. Well, sum of any two $2\times 2$ matrices is an element of $M_{22}$. You showed $u+v\notin S$, i.e $S$ is not closed under vector addition. Thus $S$ is not a vector space under *restriction binary operation* (addition and scalar multiplication).

Comment: @P.Lawrence Thanks a lot. Can you recommend a good book related to linear algebra?

Comment: @user264745 Thanks a lot. I was just wondering whether it was a subset other than 
 the question asked in the problem.

Comment: @BlueScreen I'll  suggest a very old book: Algebra by W.L. Ferrar- old-fashioned but  excellent treatment of determinants and permutations , working over the real or complex numbers but most of what he does that that does not depend on any special properties of those fields can be applied word-for-word to arbitrary fields-indeed to an arbitrary commutative ring with identity. Next, look at the first chapers of Zariski and Samuel's Commutative Algebra vol. 1 and E.A. Maxwell's 2 books "The Methods of Plane Projective Geometry... " and "General Homogeneous Coordinates inSpace of 3..."

Comment: @P.Lawrence Thank you so much. I will constantly try to study hard with the materials you told me and get good results.